# Is it possible to store a string and an int in one list?

Tags: c#, xna

I want to do a list of scores. In addition, the name of the child should be saved in that list too. After adding scores and names to the list, the list is sorted so that the lowest score is the first entry in the list. But I always get this error message:

> Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' requires 1
>   type arguments

What is wrong? Is it not possible to store names and scores in one list? What should I change?

```
SpriteFont Scores;
Random random = new Random();
List<string> NamesList = new List<string>();
List<string,int> NamesAndPointsList = new List<string,int>();

protected override void LoadContent()
{
  spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
  Scores = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Arial");

  NamesList.Add("Veronica");
  NamesList.Add("Michael");
  NamesList.Add("Christina");

  for (int j = 0; j <= NamesList.Count - 1; j++)
  {
    int Points = random.Next(101);
    NamesAndPointsList.Add(NamesList[j],Points);
  }
  NamesAndPointsList.Sort();
}
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
  GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
  spriteBatch.DrawString(Scores, NamesAndPointsList[0].ToString() + ";" + NamesAndPointsList[1].ToString() + ";" + NamesAndPointsList[2].ToString(), new Vector2(200, 200), Color.White);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: it's possible if you declare the `List<string>` as `List<object>` instead but for what you are doing sounds like you want a Dictionary instead

Comment: You should use a `Dictionary`, it will be much faster and easier to use in this situation compared to using a list with your own `Object` or a `Tuple`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Tuple`, create your own `Object`, or use a [Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary), which is ideal for what you are trying to do. A `Dictionary` will work *better* in this situation compared to a `List` because it can easily perform lookups.

The `Dictionary` type provides fast lookups with keys to get values. With it we use keys and values of any type, including ints and strings.

```
Dictionary<string,int> Users = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

Basicly, the **Key** which is a `string` is the username and the **Value** which is an `int` is the score.

To add a new user you can do this

```
 Users.Add("Michael",0); //Create new user named Michael, who starts with 0 points
```

Now you want to get Michael score possibly, you can quickly find it by doing this

```
 int Score = Users["Michael"];
```

I also don't see a need to has a `Names`and `NameAndPoints` list, you can just use one.

Comment: I agree, a Dictionary is the better solution. Did not include that as the question title was storing both a string and int in a List, but you are correct. So @Tommy, you should make this one as the anwser

Answer (score 4):

The definition is List which indeed requires a single type.

But what is preventing you from defining that type?

```
public struct User
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public int Score { get; set;}
}

var users = List<User>();
```

or if you do not want to define the class

```
var users = List<Tuple<string, int>>();
```

If however you simply want a list that can hold instances of multiple types
nothing prevents you from using an ´ArrayList` or List of object.. although I would avoid that.